# iOS: What would be a strategy for designing a form based app that looks good on all iOS devices?

Tags: ios

I am currently upgrading an app that was designed for iPhone 4s. It looks great. However, with the larger iPhone sizes there is a lot of space at the bottom of one of the scenes. It is formed based if that gives you an idea about what it looks like. In the iPhone 4s case I designed the scene so that there is no real estate at the bottom and it fits perfectly and looks great. This is not the case with the larger iPhone sizes. It looks just kind of just scrolled up. I am not sure what the general design strategy is for this? I would appreciate some suggestions on how to deal with form based scenes so that they fit the entire screen no matter what size iPhone they are being displayed on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to use Auto Layout and add constraints to your views.

Comment: Use auto layout to space the views appropriately for the screen size. One way would be to use spacer views to spread your views evenly down the screen. There are several answers here on SO about doing that.

Comment: I learned a little bit about constraints. However, it doesn't seem to solve my problem. On the iPhone 4 there isn't enough real estate for everything and on the iPhone 5 there is too much real estate at the bottom. The constraint I was working was is called Top Space to Top Layout Guide. What am I missing? For some reason, I thought it would scale it depending on the size of the device.